# django - Automate creation of models.py file?

Tags: mysql, django

Is there a way to automatically create the models.py model definition when you already have an existing database? 
I have a complicated database with tables and relationships already setup up in MySQL, and would like to avoid creating the models.py file from scratch if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use :

```
./manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

According to the documentation :

> The inspectdb utility introspects the database pointed to by your
>   settings file, determines a Django model representation for each of
>   your tables, and prints the Python model code to standard output.

More information in the [Django Book 2.0 - Chapter 18](http://djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter18/):

Comment: Thanks Sandro...works really well, including picking up raw table name, but using a nicer looking alias (caps/non-caps) via the class Meta: TABLE and db_column= directives which was a bonus given my original table names weren't entirely friendly.

Comment: However that utility isn't magical, be shure to review the output carefully, specially relationships.